# How to pass a proper description into bank statement using Stripe payment gateway

Tags: php, json, transactions, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Does anyone knows how to pass a proper description (the description to be displayed in bank statement) when user making payment using Stripe payment gateway?

I have a script for Stripe payment integrated into my website, and the payment can be done successfully and captured in Stripe.com, but in the bank statement, it does not show a proper description such as a proper order number. This is hard to identify the payment belongs to which trx.

Is there anyway that we can send order number to be displayed in the bank statement for a successful payment?

[image: sample bank statement]

Part of the codes as shown below:

```
$session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
            "success_url" => "payment-success.php?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            "cancel_url" => "payment-cancel.php",
            "payment_method_types" => ['card'],
            "mode" => 'payment',
            "line_items" => [
                [
                   "price_data" =>[
                    "currency" =>"usd",
                    "product_data" =>[
                        "name"=> "Subscription (".$reference_no.")",
                        "description" => $order_desc
                       ],
                    "unit_amount" => $total_price
                   ],
                   "quantity" => 1
                                                       
                ]
            ],

   ]);
    echo json_encode($session);
```

Comment: I think that this needs to be asked to Stripe team.

Comment: @hassan stripe team didn't provide answer upon asking, their support quite lousy when it comes to certain kind of questions, probably they don't know the answer

Comment: @azmanx for dev support it's better to either post on stack overflow as you did now or you can join the official [Stripe Discord server](https://stripe.com/go/developer-chat)

Comment: @Tarzan thanks for sharing and advice. It was so hard to find a solid help when I first started using Stripe about 3 months ago with a very little knowledge of payment gateway, json, php and mysql. What I did was just Google if I need help, sometimes I found the solution but sometimes no solutions. Stripe support not so helpful, it was very hard to explain my problem to them, end up no solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `payment_intent_data.statement_descriptor` parameter as suggested [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-statement_descriptor)

So basically your code would look something like

```php
$session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
            "success_url" => "payment-success.php?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            "cancel_url" => "payment-cancel.php",
            "payment_method_types" => ['card'],
            "mode" => 'payment',
            "payment_intent_data" => [
                "statement_descriptor" => "My Custom Bank Statement Descriptor"
            ],
            "line_items" => [
                [
                   "price_data" =>[
                    "currency" =>"usd",
                    "product_data" =>[
                        "name"=> "Subscription (".$reference_no.")",
                        "description" => $order_desc
                       ],
                    "unit_amount" => $total_price
                   ],
                   "quantity" => 1
                                                       
                ]
            ],

   ]);
    echo json_encode($session);
```

Comment: i managed to pass a proper desc. into bank statement upon making successful payment, but "statement_descriptor" has its own syntax that we need to follow, otherwise the page stuck at merchant and never going to go to Stripe. ur solution works well. thanks

Comment: that's correct you can look at the requirements [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/account/statement-descriptors#requirements)